# Fast way to construct a matrix in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

I have been browsing through the questions, and could find some help, but I prefer having confirmation by asking it directly. So here is my problem.

I have an (numpy) array `u` of dimension N, from which I want to build a square matrix `k` of dimension N^2. Basically, each matrix element `k(i,j)` is defined as `k(i,j)=exp(-|u_i-u_j|^2)`.

My first *naive* way to do it was like this, which is, I believe, Fortran-like:

```
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(N):
    k[i][j]=np.exp(np.sum(-(u[i]-u[j])**2))
```

However, this is extremely slow. For N=1000, for example, it is taking around 15 seconds.
My other way to proceed is the following (inspired by other questions/answers):

```
i, j = np.ogrid[:N,:N]
k = np.exp(np.sum(-(u[i]-u[j])**2,axis=2))
```

This is way faster, as for N=1000, the result is almost instantaneous.
So I have two questions.

1) Why is the first method so slow, and why is the second one so fast ?

2) Is there a faster way to do it ? For N=10000, it is starting to take quite some time already, so I really don't know if this was the "right" way to do it.

Thank you in advance !

P.S: the matrix is symmetric, so there must also be a way to make the process faster by calculating only the upper half of the matrix, but my question was more related to the way to manipulate arrays, etc.

Comment: Basically vectorization vs. no vectorization. The first example shows the potentially slow behaviour of python-loops. (btw: ```k[i][j]``` this looks wrong, if you are talking about numpy-arrays here; if it's a list of lists, you got one more reason for slow behaviour!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a small remark, there is no need to use `np.sum` if `u` can be re-written as `u = np.arange(N)`. Which seems to be the case since you wrote that it is of dimension `N`.

1) First question:
Accessing indices in Python is slow, so best is to not use [] if there is a way to not use it. Plus you call multiple times `np.exp` and `np.sum`, whereas they can be called for vectors and matrices. So, your second proposal is better since you compute your `k` all in once, instead of elements by elements.

2) Second question:
Yes there is. You should consider using only numpy functions and not using indices (around 3 times faster):

```
k = np.exp(-np.power(np.subtract.outer(u,u),2))
```

(NB: You can keep `**2` instead of `np.power`, which is a bit faster but has smaller precision)

---

**edit** (Take into account that `u` is an array of tuples)

With tuple data, it's a bit more complicated:

```
ma = np.subtract.outer(u[:,0],u[:,0])**2
mb = np.subtract.outer(u[:,1],u[:,1])**2
k = np.exp(-np.add(ma, mb))
```

You'll have to use twice `np.substract.outer` since it will return a 4 dimensions array if you do it in one time (and compute lots of useless data), whereas `u[i]-u[j]` returns a 3 dimensions array.

I used `np.add` instead of `np.sum` since it keep the array dimensions.

NB: I checked with

```
N = 10000
u = np.random.random_sample((N,2))
```

I returns the same as your proposals. (But 1.7 times faster)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, I understand now what the vectorization is. To reply to your first small remark (also linked to the second question): actually I said `u` was of dimension N to simplify my question ;). But as it is now in the code, each element of u has the form `u[i]=(a,b)`, hence the need for the sum. I briefly tried your code, but it doesn't seem to work in this case. I'll give it another try later ;).

Comment: @Leinahtan You should have precise in your question that it was an array of tuples. It's good to simplify so people can reproduce your problem but not too much since we might not answer well to your question. Anyway, I updated my answer with a new proposal, don't forget to accept it if it answers your question or leave me a comment if there is still a problem :)

Comment: Excellent, thank you ! I had actually managed to use your first answer to improve my code, but by "cheating" (using 2 arrays of dimension `N` instead of 1 array of dimension `(N,2)`), but it's more explicit with your code.